# Django formtools user registrations password

Tags: django, django-formtools

Trying to create user using django-formtools.

forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2')

class CustomProfileCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'email')
```

views.py

```
class SignupWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "user/registration.html"
    form_list = [CustomUserCreationForm, CustomProfileCreateForm]
    instance = None

    def get_form_instance(self, step):
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = User()
        return self.instance

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        self.instance.save()
        return render(self.request, 'done.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })
```

All are ok except password. Password is not set. How to save form correctly

Answer (score 0):

Password for users are set with the *set_password* method of the user models.

The *password1* and *password2* fields are not fields of the *User* model, but fields of the *UserCreationForm*. You should call the *save* method of your CustomUserCreationForm instead of the *save* method of your user.

To understand better how all this work, I suggest you take a look at the [*UserCreationForm.save*](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a43e2f66d76fddd791ff0b88361faba304447ff9/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L134) method.

Comment: I got your point. My question is how to do that using formtools

Comment: Your validated CustomerCreationCreationForm shoud be your first form_list element.. So get the form from here and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem initially:

```
class RegistrationWizardView(SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = DefaultStorage()
    template_name = "patient/registration.html"
    form_list = [CustomUserCreationForm, CustomProfileCreateForm]
    instance = None

    def get_form_instance(self, step):
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = User()
        return self.instance

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        for form in form_list:
            data.update(**form.cleaned_data)
        if data.get('password1', None):
            data.update({'password': data['password1']})
            data.pop('password1')
            data.pop('password2')
        User.objects.create_user(**data)
        return redirect(reverse_lazy('account_login'))
```